# area 51 proposal - Math review

Tags: discussion, area51

Recently I created a new proposal at area 51; it's called Math Review (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90443/math-review), and it is intended to be a Q&A site concerning troubles one finds while reading text books and articles. Mostly the troubles are bad typos, but not always; for instance I recently found in chapter 6 of a classic book a reference for a theorem that was proved in chapter 4, but when one consults the reference, there is no such theorem.

Articles are also abundant in bad typos and this leads to trouble understanding what the author is saying. Of course, after a while, the typo might be corrected, but this is not always the case, or it might take a long while.

With these ideas in mind I came to Mathematics Stackexchange.

But that site is for questions on math, which is different from issues concerning math texts. There, the focus is on the subject matter and not on the way something was written. I often tried to interpret the typo and if a problem persists I make it into a math question.

The point is, there should be a place where we could share those silent thoughts and corrections we make on a daily basis.

If this proposal turn out to be successful we might even use it as a place to discuss recent publications or pre-prints.

I kindly ask you to check it out, to see if the proposal can be improved.

Please help it become a better project.

Comment: I hope none of my edits distorted what was meant.

Comment: The difference in feedback between MO and MSE is quite interesting. (See here, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21250/math-review-proposal-on-area-51)

Comment: Tangentially related: it would be really nice to have a "matherrata.org" that was searchable by book/article title.

Comment: there is http://mathbooknotes.wikia.com/wiki/Math_Book_Notes_Wiki , It is a very good place to register the erros one finds. If no discussion is needed one might go there directly. Unfortunately there is no mathjax. Or maybe it is that I have not managed to use it properly

Comment: @SteveHuntsman In [this posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21257/8297) I provide some links to similar project. In particular, there was this question on MO: [Errata database?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3038/errata-database) However, the links given there seem go to abandoned projects. If I did not miss something, the only one which is alive is the Math Book Notes Wiki, which is linked also in the previous comment.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, Thank you for your interest and care for the subject. As you answered in the MSE post on meta questions that are obvious typos should go to the Math Book Notes Wiki and questions that retain math troubles are suitable for discussion in the forum of MSE. Therefore I created the tag Math-review and however it does not reach all its possibilities That's already a good beginning. Thank you again!

Comment: _nice!_ how about a site that also supports "study groups" that try to attack very difficult/ hard to understand papers and attempt to "flesh out" in detail sections that are too thin/ brief. also would like to add in CS (esp areas with heavy math focus). see also [are research papers hard to read?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/are-research-papers-hard-to-read) / [cstheory.se]

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that [Math Review proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90443/math-review) has been [closed](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/closing-a-proposal-after-1-year-in-definition-or-commitment).